# Pop selection off dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, handlebars.js

I have a question about popping selection from dropdown off the menu. I have a dropdown that gets dynamically populated with people's names, and I'd like the name selected to pop off the drop down menu and appear in a div next to it. The dropdown menu:

```
       <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button style="width: 100%;" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Group Members
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
            {{#each users}}
              <li data-uid={{this.u_id}}>{{this.full_name}}</li>
            {{/each}}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And the div I'd like the information (name) to appear:

```
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h2 class="text-center" style="margin-top: 0;">Selected Group Members</h2>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li data-uid={{this.u_id}} class="text-center">{{this.full_name}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

I'm imagining this can be done with some jQuery, which I'm unfortunately not too great at, so I'm not quite sure how to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can we see the javascript code, which pops items to div ?

Comment: The names that populate the dropdown all come from a database table, hence the {{#each users}}, and then gets assigned a data-uid based off its user ID (u_id). I was hoping that would be enough to be able to pop off the user selected and make his full_name appear in the next div. @Ashot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should does the work. Please check.

```
// selected element
var selections = [];
// container that holds selections 
var listContainer = $('.container .list-unstyled');

// sorting array of objects by provided field
var sortBy = function (arr, field) {
    return arr.sort(function (a, b) {
       if (a[field].toLowerCase() < b[field].toLowerCase()) return -1;
       if (a[field].toLowerCase() > b[field].toLowerCase()) return 1;
       return 0;
    });
};

// redraw list on container
var reorder = function(){
   listContainer.html('');
   for(var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++){
      listContainer.append('<li data-uid=' + selections.id + '>' + selections.value + '</li>');
   }
}

// list items click handler
$('ul.list-unstyled li').click(function(){
   selections.push({
      id: $(this).attr('data-uid'),
      value: $(this).text()
   });

  selections = sortBy(selections, 'name');
});
```

Comment: @LearningJS888 you can customize as you want.